# How can I support older xaml version and still use new controls from the newer version.

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

I got a warning while building my xaml project:

> The type ‘SvgImageSource’ is not available in the target platform
>   minimum version (10.0.14393.0)

I understand that I'm getting this because 14393 does not have an SvgImageSource control.

I still want to use the control and I also want to support 14393. Is that possible? Is there a way for me to create an alternative control for the older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be possible starting from the Creator's Update (15063) with [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml).

> Conditional XAML provides a way to use the `ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent` method in XAML markup. This lets you set properties and instantiate objects in markup based on the presence of an API without needing to use code behind. It selectively parses elements or attributes to determine whether they will be available at runtime.

I suppose you're using the control for SVGs. If you really need to run on older Windows 10 versions, have a look at this [post](http://www.igrali.com/2015/12/24/how-to-render-svg-in-xaml-windows-10-uwp/) from Igor Ralic on the [Mntone.SvgForXAML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mntone.SvgForXaml/) library. That will be a lot easier than trying to create the control yourself.

Extra note: if you're still working on the app and are not releasing in the next few weeks, then it might be an option to skip straight to the Creator's Update. Already [over 65% of the devices](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/which-windows-10-version-should-i-target) are on 15063 or higher in August and it's raising every week.

Comment: but some will remain at 1607 forever. MS will patch the 1607 for all incompatible devices like tablets with [old Z2xxx CPUs until the original 8.1 support ends in 2023](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-agrees-to-extend-support-deadline-for-clover-trail-pcs/): " To keep our customers secure, we will provide security updates to these specific devices running the Windows 10 Anniversary Update until January of 2023, which aligns with the original Windows 8.1 extended support period."

Comment: Those are Q2 2013 processors. My personal response would be: time to get a new device if you want my app. It's similar to the iPhone 4s / 5C (Q2 2013) not supporting ios11. It's a business decision each app maker has to make for himself. Is the extra work for backward compatibility (creating own control) worth the few extra users? Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: this was just a notice, that there are users who have to stay at the older 14393. so consider this in development.